# JS function "Deep comparison". Object comparison

Tags: javascript, comparison, deepequals

I wanted to implement JS function "Deep comparison" and encounter on one interesting feature.

1st case -

```js
var arrValuesObjA = [{is: "an"}, 2];
var arrValuesObjB = [{is: "an"}, 2];

console.log(Array.isArray(arrValuesObjA), arrValuesObjA);
//true Array [ {…}, 2 ]   // 0: Object { is: "an" } 1: 2 length: 2
console.log(Array.isArray(arrValuesObjB), arrValuesObjB);
// true Array [ {…}, 2 ]  // 0: Object { is: "an" } 1: 2 length: 2


for (let i = 0; i < arrValuesObjA.length; i++) {
  console.log(arrValuesObjA[i] === arrValuesObjB[i]);
  // First iteration - false,   second iteration - true.
  // Means Object { is: "an" } from arrValuesObjA[0] don't equal to Object { is: "an" } from arrValuesObjB[0] !!!
}
```

But look into the 2nd case.

2nd case -

```js
let objA = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}, objB = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};

var arrKeysObjA = Object.keys(objA);
var arrKeysObjB = Object.keys(objB);
var arrValuesObjA = [];
var arrValuesObjB = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arrKeysObjA.length; i++) {
  arrValuesObjA.push(objA[arrKeysObjA[i]]);
}

for (let i = 0; i < arrKeysObjB.length; i++) {
  arrValuesObjB.push(objA[arrKeysObjB[i]]);
}

console.log(Array.isArray(arrValuesObjA), arrValuesObjA);
// true Array [ {…}, 2 ]   // 0: Object { is: "an" } 1: 2 length: 2 // the same as in 1st case!
console.log(Array.isArray(arrValuesObjB), arrValuesObjB);
// true Array [ {…}, 2 ]   // 0: Object { is: "an" } 1: 2 length: 2 // the same as in 1st case!

for (let i = 0; i < arrKeysObjA.length; i++) {
  console.log(arrValuesObjA[i] === arrValuesObjB[i]);
  // First iteration - true!!!,   second iteration - true.
  // Means Object { is: "an" } from arrValuesObjA[0] equal to Object { is: "an" } from arrValuesObjB[0] !!!
}
```

In 1st case Object { is: "an" } from arrValuesObjA[0] don't equal to Object { is: "an" } from arrValuesObjB[0] but in the 2nd case they are equal.

Can anyone explain  what's going on?
I think it somehow related with copy by value and copy by reference but i'm not sure.

Comment: Solved! It was typo. Thaks Giorgi Moniava!

Comment: FYI, there is an `Object.values` method you can use. `var arrValuesObjA = Object.values(objA);`

Comment: This is an experimental technology (Object.values) don't all browser support it. @clockwork

Comment: It's not experimental; it's a fully standardized feature. As to browser support, it can be polyfilled, but that's up to you. You could use `.map()` instead, which would still be cleaner than the loops. `var arrValuesObjA = Object.keys(objA).map(k => objA[k]);` The arrow function can be replaced with the `function` syntax if your list of supported browsers can't handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrKeysObjA.length; i++) {
    arrValuesObjA.push(objA[arrKeysObjA[i]]);
}

for (let i = 0; i < arrKeysObjB.length; i++) {
    arrValuesObjB.push(objA[arrKeysObjB[i]]);
}
```

Look carefully in both cases above you are using `objA`.